# Maintain scroll position after submit

Tags: javascript

I’m using [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tcDGr?editors=100) as basis for my website. Under the link `Contact` I put contact form with PHP validation to check if user has filled in the fields properly.  After the submit button is clicked, either:

1. the validation message  (e.g.  “Sorry, your name is a required field” etc) is displayed, or
2. the message “Thank you for filling out the form” (if all the fields were filled properly ) is displayed.

However, the page then jumps back to the first page, showing the “About” page.  If you navigate back to “Contact” page you can see the messages. This is very annoying.

Example of my attempts can be found [here](http://webinspiration.net78.net/Codepen4/index.php):

I'm a beginner in this field and any hint or tip where to look further would be much appreciated.

Comment: use jquery/ajax form submission.

Comment: I actually followed one tutorial that processed form data with ajax. Well, I still didn't get it to work. However, I'm beginner and I want to search more this topic now. Thank you so much for giving me this direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would redirect to the original URL adding a hash to the URL that will tell your site where to go to.

When `comment.php` is being executed it would respond with a 302 redirect with `#contact` attached. Say your page is `index.html` it would redirect to

```
/index.html#contact
```

About redirect in PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

In `index.html` you'd then check for the hash and do what ever you do when clicking the link:

```
window.onload = function(){
   if (location.hash === "contact") {
      goto('#contact', this);
   }
}
```

If the pages are delived by the same page as the comment handler, e.g. `index.php` you could also post the form to `index.php` with `#contact` appended. You'll then need no redirect in PHP.

```
<form action="/index.php#contact" method="POST" ...>
  ...
</form>
```

---

1st benefit: you could build your page to work without Javascript too (useful for visitors using script blockers). The page containers would be block elements, one below the other. The `#<name>` will then automatically jump to the container that has an `id="<name>"` attribute. You need to add a CSS class to make the page containers side by side within the `onload` event.

2nd benefit: if you check the `hash` value for correct values and then pass it directly to your `goto()`, users will be able to bookmark the page and when revisiting your site will jump to the right "page".

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested: action="index.php#contact" and it works!!!       The messages after submit are seen on the screen and this is exactly what I was looking for. However, if you now (after submitting the form) want to navigate back to "About" or "Work" page you can't do it. The URL has now changed to index.php#contact and I guess I have to delete #contact part from the URL when clicked on "About" or "Work" link. But I have never been so close to the solution than now and I'm very grateful for your time. My last attempt here http://webinspiration.net78.net/Codepen5/index.php

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for everyone who helped me with this topic. 
I found one great tutorial how to submit a form with AJAX here:  http://demos.9lessons.info/contact/index.html
I used this code and it works! The result is here: 
http://webinspiration.net78.net/CodepenOriginal%20Contact/ 
Regards, Signe